# Is there a wrapper to launch Ant from a Powershell 1.0 script?

Tags: powershell, ant, powershell-1.0

I'm running a Powershell 1.0 script on Windows XP.  The bin directory in the standard Ant distribution contains a number of scripts for launching Ant from various other environments such as DOS, Perl, and Python.  Has anyone put together something similar for Powershell ?

Answer (score 3):

Simply invoke the batch file from your script:

`.\ant.bat`

Comment: Is not this the answer you were looking for?

Comment: It's a somewhat viable solution, but isn't quite what I'm looking for.  You can do that so long as you have all the appropriate variables set as $env:varname etc.  Edit: I should clarify: I think your idea is fine in situations where you have full control over the application  source code ; when you don't have full control it's not necessarily going to be possible to use the bat script.

Comment: what do you mean with _dont have full control_? Are you not using **ant** from the command line?

Comment: Correct.  It is being invoked from within another script.